# How to call some target methods before everytime new parameter apply in different test set in TestNG?

Tags: testing, testng

I need to run some presetting before every time the tests apply different parameter in TestNG. 
Says the bethod is "preset()", is there anyway I can make it run in following order?

**preset()**
Test1: 0 
Test2: 0 
Test3: 0

**preset()**
Test1: 1 
Test2: 1 
Test3: 1

**preset()**
Test1: 2 
Test2: 2 
Test3: 2

Comment: You're going to have to provide some more detail - no one is going to have any idea what you're talking about. What language is this? What testing framework?

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake, I'm talking about Testng

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use a @DataProvider.

Comment: hi Cedric~ I used @DataProvider Already. The question is about, which annoation will enable a method be called everytime before the data which provided by the data provider changed. In above example, the parameter were provided by data provider, and I used "group-by-instances="true"" to let it group by data, not by method. So how can I call the preset()method every time in the target place?

Comment: How about calling preset() in your data provider then?

Comment: if call by data provider the result will be : preset() preset() preset()Test1: 0 Test2: 0 Test3: 0

 Test1: 1 Test2: 1 Test3: 1

Test1: 2 Test2: 2 Test3: 2  It's not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the order of your test method execution you can use IMethodInterceptor interface.

Check out this [link](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors).